# RequireJS configuration for jQuery

Tags: requirejs

I'm trying to configure RequireJS to load jQuery from a different folder on my site than the `/Scripts` folder where everything else lives.  I'm watching the page load with Fiddler, and I always see the jQuery request go out for `/Scripts/jquery.js` instead of the right URL.

In my markup, I have this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/require.js")" type="text/javascript" data-main="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/main")"></script>
```

In `/Scripts/main.js` I have this:

```
require.config({
    waitSeconds: 10,
    paths: {
        "jquery": "/N2/Resources/Js/jquery-1.7",
        "modernizr": "modernizr-2.0.6-development-only"
    }
});

require(["jquery", "jquery.utility", "jquery.link-decorators", "jquery.google-analytics", "accessibility", "modernizr"], function ($) {

... omitted

});
```

In Fiddler, I see the correct modernizr request go out, but the request for jQuery goes out for `/Scripts/jquery.js`.

As a test, I changed my modernizr line to `"modernizr" : "/N2/Resources/Js/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only"`, and I see the request go out for that resource (of course it returns a 404).  So I know that RequireJS sees my configuration, and is processing it.

NOTE: I'm aware of the various ways to deal with jQuery in RequireJS.  All my plugins define modules, so out-of-order loading won't be a problem.  I'm using jQuery 1.7, which is AMD-aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  In markup in the body of my page, I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["jquery", "Rotator"], function ($, Rotator) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var homeRotator = new Rotator();
        homeRotator.initialize($('#home-rotator ul.rotator-content li'), { viewTime: 30000, transitionTime: 2500 });
    });
});
```

This is what's causing the request for `/Scripts/jquery`.  The `Rotator` module depends on `jquery`.  If I remove the `jquery` dependency here, the page loads properly.  The problem seems to be that I put my `require.config` settings into `main.js`, which is is loaded asynchronously by `require.js`.  Before `main.js` is loaded, the script above is encountered in the body, so the request for jQuery goes out to the default location, not the configured location.

I moved my configuration settings into a `<script/>` tag in the page head, and now it's working.